# Facebook Link attachment in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, attachment

How do you attach a link in ruby on rails similar to facebook link attachment where you get the title and the description of the link attached.? Could you help me with the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use Mechanize

```
my_page=Mechanize.new
my_page.get("http://google.com")
my_page.page.title
```

OR, you can use Pismo(https://github.com/peterc/pismo). Details of its usage are available on github.